# How to configure the Android App in Xamarin to use linking file?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a linking file like this documentation describe (https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker), but I don't understand where to put this file and how to set project build action to LinkingDescription like documentation describe.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the file in the same folder as the Android csproj.  To set the build action, right click and select the build action, or select the file and set the build action in the properties window.